# cat -E analog for Mac OS

Tags: bash, macos, shell, zsh, cat

I used the scripts on Linux for like a couple of years with cat -E argument to display EOL as $.

But in Mac OS cat did not support -E argument.

Any alternative to do the same thing here?
The less code is better,

Comment: Install [gnu cat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just relying on `sed` after some pipe?

I mean:

```
cat | sed -e 's/$/\$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cat -e ...
```

This will display a dollar sign ($) at the end of a line. Use `cat -etv ...` to display the ending line, tab characters as `^I` and other non-printing characters such as the carriage return as `^M`.

Comment: cat -e displays -v characters too, that's a problem